# Postgresql query returning duplicate records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query:

```
    SELECT  DISTINCT ON (users.id)
        users.id,
        users.name,
        users.email,
        users.phone,
        users.sub,
        sup.title,
        COUNT(customers.id)
    FROM  users                             
    LEFT JOIN customers ON users.id = customers.user_id
    LEFT JOIN sup_users ON users.id = sup_users.user_id
    LEFT JOIN sup ON sup.id = sup_users.sup_id
    GROUP BY users.id, users.name, users.email, users.phone, users.sub, sup.title
```

`sup_users` has this structure:

```
    Column      |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |                  Default                   | Storage | Stats target | Description 
    -------------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
    id          | integer |           | not null | nextval('sup_users_id_seq'::regclass)      | plain   |              | 
    sup_id      | integer |           | not null |                                            | plain   |              | 
    user_id     | integer |           | not null |                                            | plain   |              |
```

If it contains multiple records where there is one user_id and more than one sup_id my query contains duplicate records.

I could change the query to `SELECT DISTINCT` but am wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Why are you using the `DISTINCT ON` at all? Just don't `GROUP BY` the `sup.title`

Comment: Distinct applied on composite value for all selected column. So, what ever you have 1 user_ID, but in combination with other column's value, its no more unique user_id.

Comment: @mkRabbani: you are right about `distinct` but runnerpaul uses `distinct on (..)` which is something different

Comment: @RichardHuxton the problem with that is `COUNT(customers.id)` gets multiplied by the number of additional `sup_users` records for a particular user_id. I tried removing `sup.title` and including `COUNT(DISTINCT customers.id)` which gives the results I'm expecting. Again, I'm not sure if it's the best way to do the query of if there is a better way.

Comment: It's difficult to see what you are trying to do. Why join to `sup_users` and `sup` if you don't want them? Perhaps edit your question to give an example of what you want the query to do

Comment: Sorry, I had to edit the query. I just realised I had left sup.title out. That's the reason I need the additional tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query I ended up with:

```
SELECT  users.id,
    users.name,
    users.email,
    users.phone,
    users.sub,
    suppliers.title,
    COUNT(customer_users.id)
FROM  users                              
LEFT JOIN supplier_users ON users.id = supplier_users.user_id
LEFT JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.id = supplier_users.supplier_id
LEFT JOIN customers ON suppliers.id = customers.supplier_id
INNER JOIN customer_users ON customers.id = customer_users.customer_id AND users.id = customer_users.user_id
GROUP BY users.id, users.name, users.email, users.phone, users.sub, suppliers.title
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT u.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM customers c
        WHERE u.id = c.user_id
       ) as num_customers
FROM users u ;
```

I don't understand why you are joining in tables that you are not explicitly referencing.